# How do I concatenate fields into a single field when populating a SQL database (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, concatenation

I need to plug a load of data from a separate program into a single table (in Oracle SQL Developer). This transfer of data is going to be in one direction, meaning the system will just occasionally dump a load of data in the table, replacing what was there before. I therefore don't have to worry about being able to update individual fields. I also can't modify how this system transfers the data into my table, which means I am stuck with mapping its fields to my column headers (it's just sending the data using `INSERT`s behind the scenes).

I want the table to have a unique `TRANSACTION_ID` column. However, each `TRANSACTION_ID` might have multiple `TRANSACTION_TYPE`s, so I will receive multiple rows for each ID with a different `TRANSACTION_TYPE`. e.g:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TRANSACTION_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE) VALUES (1000, TT35)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TRANSACTION_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE) VALUES (1000, TT40)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TRANSACTION_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE) VALUES (1000, TT12)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TRANSACTION_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE) VALUES (1001, TT12)
......etc.
```

I want to concatenate these into a single field separated by commas, so the final table would look like:

```
 TRANSACTION_ID     TRANSACTION_TYPES
-----------------------------------------
  1000               TT35,TT40,TT12
  1001               TT12
  1002               TT40,TT23
```

I realise that this is de-normalising the data, but since I do not need to update it I am not overly concerned.

I understand the way to do this usually is by using a `MERGE`, but since I am stuck with the `INSERT` actions of the source system I cannot use this. Is it possible to do this using a trigger? I've run into mutating table errors etc. in my previous attempts.

The last resort might be to store the `TRANSACTION_TYPE`s in a separate table, treat the data, and then delete the second table, but that seems ridiculously over-complicated.

Is there a straight-forward way of doing this that I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You probably *could* do this with a trigger, but I wouldn't recommend it.  The trigger would need to replace the `insert`, sometimes doing an insert and sometimes concatenating the values.

Two other options.  First, load the data into a staging table and then create a new table that your process.

The second is to just ignore the problem and use `list_agg()` to bring the data together when you are querying it.

Comment: It would be a third party that would be using the data though, so I really need to present it to them in the format they need. I don't think relying on them using a particular query is a good idea. Is the staging table suggestion similar to what I described?

Comment: @MDalt . . . You can load the data into a table and then create a view or materialized view with the data in the format you want.